# Best practice's for firing methods with an anonymous querystring name (C#)

Tags: c#

All sorry if the question is a little vague but I appear to be going around in circles, when trying to figure out best practice's with "firing methods with an anonymous querystring name"

When I refer to "anonymous" It just means I don't want to know the actual value nor do i expect anyone else to know.

The code below is on a page_load event of a webform, which has a querystring of "AddonType" that contains either "blog, news or services". I would then need to send that value to my "facade" which builds out the content i need.

```
//Does main addon type querstring exist
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Request.QueryString["addOnType"]))
{
    //Does a addons exist
    if (contentFacade.HasAddons() == true)
    {
        //Has addon
         if(Request.QueryString["addOnType"] == "blog")
         {
           //I know this is a blog addon so return 
           //a string, with content fetched from facade

           //Add string to page
           contentFacade.GetLatestBlogPosts();
         }
    }
    else 
    { 
        //No addons please see message
        Response.Redirect("/notifications/SystemError/");
    }
}
else 
{ 
    //Redirect to 404 / 
    Response.Redirect("/notifications/404/");
}
```

So the idea is to run some methods in the "true" block. For Example if the querystring has a value of "blog" then run method "GetLatestBlogPosts".

Is there anyway to fire methods based on a querystring without conditionals and hard coding values?

Because the querstring "AddonType" can literally be any content type IE blog, news, services etc...I'm ideally looking for a better design practice / approach that could handle this scenario.

I fully appreciate everyone's time and thank you in advanced.

Any elaboration required, then please give me a shout.

Regards,

Comment: Yes, [Reflection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) with `GetType().GetMethod(Request.QueryString["addOnType"]).Invoke(...)`. **Absolutely** do many security checks (just to begin you may decorate your methods with an attribute and only those methods are callable).

Comment: If you are willing to completely overhaul your design, you should consider switching to a [REST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) architecture.

Comment: @mbeckish I'm intrigued. Can you give me an edge case, in your own words?

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti Could this be mocked up in an answer?

Comment: You could consider the [Factory Pattern](http://www.dotnetperls.com/factory). FYI Don't do this: `if (contentFacade.HasAddons() == true)`, just do `if (contentFacade.HasAddons())`. Also, considering you use `Request.QueryString["addOnType"]` twice, store the value of the first request in a variable and use that one. This way you wouldn't need to update `"addOnType"` in multiple places should that parameter name ever change.

Comment: @BCdotWEB I fully appreciate your comment.